# Docker nginx proxy to host

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

**Short description:**

Nginx running on docker, how to configure nginx so that it forwards calls to host.

**Long description:**

We have one web application which communicates to couple of backends (lets says rest1, rest2 and rest3). We are responsible for `rest1`.

Lets consider that I started `rest1` manually on my pc and running on 2345 port. I want nginx (which is running in docker) to redirect all call to`rest1` to my own running instance(note, the instance is running on host, not any container and not in docker). And for `rest2` and `rest3` to some other docker node or may be some other server (who cares).

**What I am looking for is:**

1. `docker-compose.yml` configurations (if needed).
2. nginx configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Docker Compose file version 3 you don't need any special config for `docker-compose.yml` file at all, just use the special DNS name `host.docker.internal` to reach a host service, as on the following `nginx.conf` example:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    upstream host_service {
       server host.docker.internal:2345;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/http_access.log  combined;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/http_error.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://host_service;

            proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $realip_remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: host.docker.internal looks like it's not supported on linux https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264

Answer (score 13):

Configure nginx like the following (make sure you replace IP of Docker Host) and save it as `default.conf`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<IP of Docker Host>;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Now bring up the container:

```
docker run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 -v /path/to/nginx/config/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf nginx
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't try it yet, but i will soon. Is there anyway to automate the process? I mean the host IP? Because we want to develop something that will run on every machine.

Comment: use a bash script, first `hostname -I`, then `grep` the range, then `sed` into the config file and replace.

Comment: none of those ip addresses seem to work. I've even tried 0.0.0.0:5000 and I get 502 Bad Gateway.

Comment: @MarissaLevy You have a service on your docker-host that is listening on port 5000? Did you verified its working using a browser (open browser, <ipofdockerhost:5000>)? if it works, replace the ip of docker host in the configuration and add :5000 at the end of it.

Comment: @marissalevy 0.0.0.0 is wrong means any interface on the local mache which is the docker container, replace it with host ip address

Comment: @FarhadFarahi The only way to access the host from a container is via the external IP address?

Comment: @MarissaLevy You can use dns too, if docker-host has a name on DNS Server available to the container.

Comment: in container run `route | grep default | awk '{print $2 " docker.host"}' >> /etc/hosts` then you try to `ping docker.host`

Comment: If docker-for-mac is host, IP is `host.docker.internal` - https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#per-container-ip-addressing-is-not-possible

Comment: On a linux host, you can issue "ip -4 a sh" to see ipv4 ipaddresses for the host server. If you know the network interface name,  you can be more specific -  "ip -4 a sh (interface name)"

Answer (score 5):

**Solution 1**

Use `network_mode: host`, this will bind your nginx instance to host's network interface. 
This could result in conflicts when running multiple nginx containers: every exposed port is binded to host's interface.

**Solution 2**

I'm running more nginx instances for every service I would like expose to outside world. 
To keep the nginx configurations simple and avoid binding every nginx to host use the container structure:

`dockerhost` - a dummy container with `network_mode: host`

`proxy` - nginx container used as a proxy to host service,

link `dockerhost` to `proxy`, this will add an `/etc/hosts` entry in `proxy` contianer - we can use 'dockerhost' as a hostname in nginx configuration.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  dockerhost:
    image: alpine
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c "tail -f /dev/null"
    network_mode: host
  proxy:
    image: nginx:alpine
    links: 
     - dockerhost:dockerhost
    ports:
     - "18080:80"
    volumes:
     - /share/Container/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
```

default.conf

```
 location / {
        proxy_pass http://dockerhost:8080;
```

This method allows us to have have automated let's encrtypt certificates generated for every service running on my server. If interested I can post a gist about the solution.

Comment: Kindly share the gist

Comment: Actually I liked the second solution and it's working fine. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that solution 2 doesn't  work anymore. no dockerhost records appears in /etc/hosts of proxy container

Comment: I believe the links option is deprecated, and the trick to get a hostname defined will only work if you're using the default docker network.

Answer (score 1):

There a couple of things you have to keep in mind:

1. Docker compose (from version 3) by default uses the service name as hostname for inter container networking
2. Nginx need to know the upstream first
3. I strongly recommend mounting the default.conf directly into your docker-compose.yml.
4. Lastly you have to dockerize your backend to make use of docker internal networking.

An example repo where I use nginx and docker-compose in a full-stack project: https://gitlab.com/datails/api.

The following example have some prerequisites:

- you have a folder structure like:

  ```
  - backend/
  - frontend/
  - default.conf
  - docker-compose.yml
  ```
- Secondly the backend and front-end dit have a Dockerfile that exposes an application on port 3000.

Example `default.conf`:

```
upstream backend {
    server backend:3000;
}

upstream frontend {
    server frontend:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }

    location / {           
        proxy_pass http://frontend/;
    }
}
```

Example `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.4
    depends_on:
      - server
      - frontend
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
```

Then make sure you have your backend dockerized and called (in this case) `backend` as a service and a front-end (if needed) called frontend as a service in your docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:    
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.4
    depends_on:
      - server
      - frontend
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - '8080:80'

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend

  backend:
    build: ./backend
```

This is a bare minimum example to get started. Hope this will help future developers.

Answer (score -1):

```
server {
  listen       80;

  server_name  localhost;
  
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3000;
  }

}
```

Docker expose host address is host.docker.internal in Mac os