# How do I set up docker and nginx for local development

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

## Context

I am trying to build out a local development environment and I am struggling to get it to work. I want docker and docker compose to run nginx as a reverse proxy and a postgresql database

Project Structure

```
my-app/
├─ server/ (fastify node server)
├─ client/ (sveltekit dev server)
├─ nginx/
│  ├─ Dockerfile
│  ├─ default.conf
├─ docker-compose.yml
```

I want the only prerequisites to be Node, git and docker. I to be able to clone the project, start docker compose, and then start the two projects individually

## Prior Research

I've read through the nginx Beginners guide and several pieces of the nginx documentation but I find their docs fairly unapproachable. I also have found several guides that have my client and server running inside docker containers and set up as separate services within docker compose. That is not the end goal, but unfortunately I have not gotten those to work either.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438381/docker-nginx-proxy-to-host) seems close and I found it helpful. But it’s still not working.

To start, I'm just trying to get everything to work on http://localhost:4000 in order to remove some of the complexity

This is my best attempt thus far:

```
    ##########################
    # docker-compose.yml
    ##########################
    
    version: '3.9'
    services:
      reverse-proxy:
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
    
    ##########################
    # nginx/Dockerfile
    ##########################
    FROM nginx:1.21.3
    COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf/
    
    ##########################
    # nginx/default.conf
    ##########################
    
    server {
      listen 8080;
    
      location / {
        proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:8080;
      }
    
      location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3000;
      }
    }
```

With this set up, I can hit http://localhost:3000/api/ and get my json response from the server, but when I try and hit http://localhost:8080/api/, I get the standard nginx 502 response and nginx does not successfully reach my node server. The nginx logs give me this error:

```
     2021/11/16 12:38:39 [error] 34#34: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.65.2:3000/api/", host: "localhost:8080"
```

I don't know where the IP address comes from up above, but if I hit http://192.168.65.2:3000/api/ locally, then the browser just spins and spins.

## End Goal

I am looking for a properly configured `docker-compose.yml` and a single, relatively simple nginx file for the moment that gets mapped into the default. HTTPS and a custom URL are really later problems. For now, I just want to be able to hit my nginx reverse proxy within a docker container and properly route to my two locally running node servers (one an API server and one a sveltekit dev server - neither inside docker containers).

Thank you in advance for any help!

### Edit (After changes suggested by Robert-Jan Kuyper)

I'm now running basically this:

```
##########################
# docker-compose.yml
##########################

version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.4
    depends_on:
      - api
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.local.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
  api:
    build: ./api
    hostname: api
    command: node src/app.js
    volumes:
      - ./server/src:/app/src


##########################
# nginx/default.conf
##########################

upstream api_server {
    server api:3000;
}

server {
  listen 8080;

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://api_server;
  }
}

##########################
# api/Dockerfile
##########################

FROM node:16.9.0

# docker workdir
WORKDIR /home/usr/app

# copy files
COPY . .

# build the app
RUN npm ci

# expose at port 3000
EXPOSE 3000


CMD ["node", "src/app.js"]
```

Unfortunately, it is still failing with this:

```
[error] 29#29: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.2:3000/api/", host: "localhost:8080"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There a couple of things you have to keep in mind:

1. Docker compose by default uses the service name as hostname for inter container networking
2. Nginx need to know the upstream first
3. You don't need Nginx in a Dockerfile, use it directly in `docker-compose.yml` instead. And mount your config file into the container.
4. You need to dockerize your front-end and back-end to connect them to nginx
5. Always expose on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` inside your docker container, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66118969/11067065).

An example repo where I use nginx, docker and docker-compose: https://gitlab.com/datails/api .

Example `default.conf`:

```
upstream api_server {
    server api:3000;
}

upstream frontend {
    server frontend:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api_server;
    }

    location / {           
        proxy_pass http://frontend/;
    }
}
```

Example `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.4
    depends_on:
      - server
      - frontend
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
```

Then make sure you have your front-end dockerized and called `frontend` as a service in your docker-compose like:

```
version: '3.8'
services:    
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.4
    depends_on:
      - server
      - frontend
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - '8080:80'

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    command: npm run start
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/src:/home/usr/app/src

  api:
    build: ./api
    command: npm run start
    volumes:
      - ./api/src:/home/usr/app/src
```

Note you don't need a port because you use inter container communication.

Comment: This is definitely helpful, and a step in the right direction. I’m curious though, it seems like this wouldn’t get live code changes, right? Is there not a way to proxy out of the docker compose network so I can run them on the host machine natively?

Comment: What do you mean? When it comes to hot reloading, you can mount your src dir into your docker container src dir. That's why the volumes are there. Then all changes locally, will directly be mounted into the container as well. Therefor, personally I always use a different command when starting a container in `docker-compose` for example: `npm run start:debug`. You can see the examples in the gitlab repo.

Comment: Hot reloading is what I was referring to. I’ll give this a shot really soon. It looks right though

Comment: So I've changed my nginx config to look like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.4
    depends_on:
      - server
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.local.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
  server:
    build: ./server
    expose:
      - 3000
    volumes:
      - ./server/src:/app/src
```
And now I'm getting this error:
```
021/11/16 17:59:08 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "api:3000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:7
```
I'm just trying to get nginx -> server talking for now

Comment: That is because you haven’t defined a service in your docker-compose.yml called api. So the hostname api does not exist. Add a new service in the docker-compose.yml that builds your api and call the service api, and expose it to port 3000. Then nginx will find it. Please have a look in the GitLab repo in the server directory. There you see a Dockerfile, that file is being referenced to from the docker-compose.yml.

Comment: thank you so much for your help thus far! I've been combing through the GitLab repo and I'm still stuck. I've changed the way I'm trying to set this up quite a bit and it's still not working. I've added edits showing where I am and what the error message. I just can't figure it out :/ That error is from the nginx logs when I visit `http://localhost:8080/api/` in my browser

Comment: Is the result a 404 or a 502? If it is 404 it has to do because in the `default.conf` the location has the `/api` prefix. This affects your api, as it must also have this prefix. So either change the `/api` prefix in the `default.conf` or add a prefix in your api with `/api` to all endpoints.

Comment: It is a 502. My server is showing no logs at all. As far as I can tell, it’s not being touched

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239319/discussion-between-sam-and-robert-jan-kuyper).